# Stopping a double animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my `UserControl.Resources` i have defined a `Storyboard` which triggers a `DoubleAnimation` to set the `Opactiy`.

```
<Storyboard AutoReverse="True" x:Key="BlinkingStoryBoard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.1" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
</Storyboard>
```

This Storyboard is applied to a grid when the UserControl is loaded:

```
<Grid Name="ImagePlaceHolder">
    <Rectangle Fill="#D52B1E" Width="75" Height="75"/>
    <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Images/cross.png" Width="75" Height="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" x:Name="Cross"/>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BlinkingStoryBoard}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

From my code-behind I want to stop this animation, but I cant stop it!

```
((Storyboard)uc.FindResource("BlinkingStoryBoard")).Stop();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to stop it based on a condition or do you want it just to run once? Your question is bit unclear in that matter.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I just want to stop it. I have a method which is triggered when a property is changed. From this method I want to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e89a9821-120e-4ddf-996f-4c24075e4883/howto-control-a-storyboard-in-code-after-it-is-started-in-xaml?forum=wpf).

The main idea is that you need to call the storyboard Stop method passing the container of the storyboard.

You should try replacing the stop call with this:

```
((Storyboard)uc.FindResource("BlinkingStoryBoard")).Stop(ImagePlaceHolder);
```

Also from the reference, it shows that you can name your `BeginStoryboard`, for example:

```
<BeginStoryboard Name="MyStoryboardStarter" Storyboard="{StaticResource BlinkingStoryBoard}"/>
```

Now in the code behind you can find your storyboard more easily and stop it like this:

```
MyStoryboardStarter.Storyboard.Stop(ImagePlaceHolder);
```

Hope this helps.